# How to change activity presentation?

Tags: android

I want to set diffrent slide presentation for each activity.

Is this possible, and how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean a different orientation? If so, this is specified on your activity in your manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".PhoneActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

You have you few options you can use when setting `screenOrientation`. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen for all of them.